# ERROR: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c

ERROR: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Hi I would like to know if someone would have the solution to solve my problem I do not understand why it is said that tab [c] is not initialized it puts me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void maloc(int x)
{
    char* tab = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int i = 1 ;
    int swap;
    if(x > 0)
    {
        tab = malloc((x+1) * sizeof(char)); // On alloue de la mémoire pour le tableau
        if(tab == 0) // On vérifie si l'allocation a marché ou non
        {
            exit(0); // On arrête tout
        }
        else
        { 
            while (tab[c] != '/0' )
            {
                tab[c] = i + '0';
                i++;
                c++;
            }
            c = 0;
        }
    }
    free(tab);// On libère la mémoire allouée avec malloc, on n'en a plus besoin
}

int main() 
{
    maloc(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give the exact and complete error. Is it coming from valgrind? It should tell you the exact line of code that has that error and you should give that info in the post.

Comment: `while (tab[c] != '/0' )`  for that `tab[c]` is an uninitalised value and that's one place the error can come from. Also, it's `'\0'` not `'/0'`. Why are you trying to check `tab[c]` in a loop that is responsible for filling in the array?

Comment: The loop should be on x, since that is the size.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand why it is said that tab [c] is not initialized

`malloc()` does not initialize the memory it provides, so immediately after you perform ...

> ```
>         tab = malloc((x+1) * sizeof(char));
> ```

... there is no value of `c` for which `tab[c]` has been initialized.  In particular, the value of `c` at that point is 0, and `tab[0]` is not initialized.

The `calloc()` function, on the other hand, does provide initialized (to all-bytes zero) allocated memory, but if you used that (and corrected the typo, `'/0'` to `'\0'`) then you should not expect any iterations of your `while` loop to be performed, as the condition would be false the first time it was tested.

I think you're trying to be too clever.  It looks like this would do what you are trying to do with the `while` loop, more clearly and easily:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                tab[i] = i + '1';
            }
```

If you really want to allocate that extra byte and initialize it to 0, then you could add ...

```
            tab[x] = 0;
```

... afterward.